# Close third party activity

Tags: android

Is it possible to close an activity which hasn't been started by your activity?

So, suppose I have an app which has MainActivity. My Mainactivity wants to close CNN app that is installed on my phone (and probably running in background). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you'll either need to have a rooted phone, OR, have created the other application yourself (so you could write code to close itself down when getting a specific broadcast)

Seeing as you want to close the CNN app, which im guessing you haven't created yourself, then no, it's not possible.
An application can't simply manipulate other applications lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly no. Because of android security model you cannot have direct access to third party activities data/methods. You could only close 3rd party activity via intent in this activity will support this kind behaviour.